# How to reboot and change termination protection of an EC2 instance programatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, multiple-instances

I am new to AWS and want to know if there is any way to how to reboot and change termination protection of an EC2 instance programmatically(using JAVA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reboot an EC2 Instance, you have to call the method [rebootInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#rebootInstances(com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.RebootInstancesRequest)) of your [AWS EC2 Java client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html).

To enable/disable termination protection, you have to modify the [setDisableApiTermination](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest.html#setDisableApiTermination(java.lang.Boolean)) of a [ModifyInstanceAttributesRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest.html) using the method as argument of the method [modifyInstanceAttribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#modifyInstanceAttribute(com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest)) of your [AWS EC2 Java client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html).

Comment: Thanks Cidian for the help

Answer (score 1):

Terminating a EC2 instance accidentally is the worst nightmare for the the AWS developer as it is near to impossible to get them back.

Going with the saying prevention is better then cure, we can call/use the following methods to prevent users from terminating

```
*public void setTerminationProtected(java.lang.Boolean terminationProtected)*
```

This method will protect and prevent Amazon EC2 instances in the cluster from shutting down due to manual intervention or due to some program

```
*public java.lang.Boolean isTerminationProtected()*
```

This method will return boolean indicating whether to protect cluster from shutting down due to manual intervention or due to some program.
For rebooting Instance one can use the following method

```
*public RebootInstancesRequest withInstanceIds(java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> instanceIds)*
```

It will send request to AWS to reboot the one or more given instances

Comment: Thanks Vikas for the help